# How to add parent name with their name using parent Id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback

I have following array which is saved in Database. i want to modify it to display like following which show their hierarchic with parent in localeName key.

```
var allLocales = [
{
    id: 123,
    localeName: 'Test',
    parentId: null
},
{
    id: 456,
    localeName: 'Test 1',
    parentId: 123
},
{
    id: 789,
    localeName: 'Test 2',
    parentId: 456
}
]
```

I want to change above array to following array by changing their display name like this using their parents.:

```
allLocales = [
{
    id: 123,
    localeName: 'Test',
    parentId: null
},
{
    id: 456,
    localeName: 'Test > Test 1',
    parentId: 123
},
{
    id: 789,
    localeName: 'Test > Test 1 > Test 2',
    parentId: 456
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this aggregation if you are using mongo 3.4+

you can use `$graphLookup` for hierarchical queries [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html)

```
db.locales.aggregate(
    [
        {$graphLookup : {
            from : "locales",
            startWith : "$parentId",
            connectFromField : "parentId",
            connectToField : "id",
            as : "parents"
            }
        },
        {$addFields : {localeName : {$substr : [{$concat : [{$reduce : {input : "$parents", initialValue : "", in : {$concat : ["$$value", " > ", "$$this.localeName"]}}}, " > " ,"$localeName"] }, 3 , 1000]}}},
        {$project : {parents : 0}}
    ]
).pretty()
```

collection

```
> db.locales.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a73dead0cfc59674782913a"), "id" : 123, "localeName" : "Test", "parentId" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a73dead0cfc59674782913b"), "id" : 456, "localeName" : "Test 1", "parentId" : 123 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a73dead0cfc59674782913c"), "id" : 789, "localeName" : "Test 2", "parentId" : 456 }
>
```

result

```
> db.locales.aggregate( [ {$graphLookup : { from : "locales", startWith : "$parentId", connectFromField : "parentId", connectToField : "id", as : "parents" } }, {$addFields : {localeName : {$substr : [{$concat : [{$reduce : {input : "$parents", initialValue : "", in : {$concat : ["$$value", " > ", "$$this.localeName"]}}}, " > " ,"$localeName"] }, 3 , 100]}}}, {$project : {parents : 0}} ] ).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a73dead0cfc59674782913a"),
    "id" : 123,
    "localeName" : "Test",
    "parentId" : null
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a73dead0cfc59674782913b"),
    "id" : 456,
    "localeName" : "Test > Test 1",
    "parentId" : 123
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a73dead0cfc59674782913c"),
    "id" : 789,
    "localeName" : "Test > Test 1 > Test 2",
    "parentId" : 456
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make recursive function to solve this problem.
I made like below and tested.
Please see the function.

```
var allLocales = [
  {  id: 123, localeName: 'Test', parentId: null },
  {  id: 456, localeName: 'Test 1',  parentId: 123 },
  {  id: 789, localeName: 'Test 2', parentId: 456 }
];


function nameRecursion(element) {
    if(element.parentId == null) {
        return element.localeName
    }else {
        var parent = allLocales.find(item => item.id === element.parentId);
        return nameRecursion(parent) + " -> " + element.localeName;
    }
}

var newArray = allLocales.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
for(var i=0; i<allLocales.length; i++){
     newArray[i].localeName = nameRecursion(allLocales[i]);
}

console.log(allLocales);
console.log(newArray);
```